# Refactoring - code samples before and after

Tags: java, refactoring, metrics, code-metrics

I'm writing master thesis about evaluation of source code metrics with a use of refactoring patterns.
I would like to examine metrics before and after set of refactorings and check how they change.

But now I'm looking for something bigger than examples from "Refactoring" by M. Fowler, "Refactoring to patterns" or "Clean code".

Does anybody know about project with this two snapshots (before/after refactoring) available?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a specific programming problem. You're more likely to find answers in the chat rooms or another forum.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will find what you are looking for. Or actually it is not clear what you are looking at. Which refactoring patterns do you want to see applied? How often? How many times? You can find all and everything...

Are you trying to replicate "Experimental Assessment of Software Metrics Using Automated Refactoring" from Ó Cinnéide et al. ?

I can point you to OpenDJ 2.6 vs. OpenDJ 3.0, where we made a LOT of refactoring changes and rewrites. However I doubt it will be very useful since a lot of things are mixed together.